# What is the equivalent of passing DefaultCredentials in WCF?

Tags: wcf, credentials, kerberos, ntlm

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252961/how-do-i-call-a-sharepoint-webservice-from-a-c-client-using-kerberos-authenticat/253259#253259) explains that when calling a .asmx web service there's no need to specify which authentication type to use:

---

```
WebServiceProxy proxy = new WebServiceProxy(); // Derived from SoapHttpClientProtocol

proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

This method works for both NTLM and Kerberos authentication. It will pass the credentials of the windows account under which the code is running.

---

What is the equivalent in WCF, that works in both NTLM and Kerberos environments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WCF you need to specify authentication in the bindings of your WCF services. Make sure the client and server use the same authentication scheme.

web.config:

```
<binding name="WindowsClientOverTcp">
    <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
    </security>
</binding>
```

Comment: So there is no way to avoid specifying the authentication? That is, you need to know if the environment is Kerberos or NTLM?

Comment: With Kerberos your client and server need to meet some specific conditions before it is used, otherwise the windows authentication will default to use NTLM